# How do I find the distinct values from 2 tables base on ID and indicator?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find the record which has the same ID and indicator but with different value. Here is my sample data.

```
declare @table1 table (id int, indicator varchar(20),value int);
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES
(11,'AC',80),
(11,'HE',90),
(12,'AC',10),
(12,'HE',80),
(13,'AC',10),
(13,'HE',10);


declare @table2 table(id int, indicator varchar(20),value int);
INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES
(11,'AC',80),
(11,'HE',90),
(12,'AC',11),
(12,'HE',80),
(13,'AC',10),
(14,'AC',10);
```

I create [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lF23vMlY)

Base on the sample data above, there will 4 scenarios:

1. 11 existing in both table, each ID with same indicator and value, so I will NOT log in record.

2. 12 with indicator 'AC' has different value from table2 (10 and 11), this is the record I need.

3. 13 existing in both table, but table 1 has 2 records, and both indicator 'AC' has same value. In this case, I only need the one which does not have match record in table 2.(In this case, its (13,'HE',10).
Please notes, there could have same situation in table 2 as well. therefore, Result for table 1 will become NULL and list the result from table 2

4. ID only existing in one of the table, for eg: 14. Then I don't need this one.

In another word, I need the record If 2 table has same ID and Indicator but with different value. If both table has same ID, but with different indicator and value, I also need to log this record.

Therefore, I do want my result to look like this.

| Table 1 ID | Table 1 Indicator | Table 1 Value | Table 2 ID | Table 2 Indicator | Table 2 Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | AC | 10 | 12 | AC | 11 |
| 13 | HE | 10 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variation on the XOR join: you need to `FULL JOIN` the two sides, but only take the results if there is a difference. The tweak here is that if the `ID` does not exist on one side then you also want to ignore those rows (similar to an `INNER JOIN`).

The best I can come up with is to use a `FULL JOIN` combined wth conditional windowed counts of both sides

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
      Table1ID = t1.id,
      Table1Indicator = t1.indicator,
      Table1Value = t1.value,
      Table2ID = t2.id,
      Table2Indicator = t2.indicator,
      Table2Value = t2.value,
      count1 = CASE WHEN t1.id IS NOT NULL THEN COUNT(t2.id) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id) END,
      count2 = CASE WHEN t2.id IS NOT NULL THEN COUNT(t1.id) OVER (PARTITION BY t2.id) END
    FROM @table1 t1
    FULL JOIN @table2 t2
      ON t2.id = t1.id
     AND t2.indicator = t1.indicator
) t
WHERE (Table1Value <> Table2Value)
   OR (Table1Value IS NULL AND count2 > 0)
   OR (Table2Value IS NULL AND count1 > 0);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/wHIMeOiF)

Note that the fiddle also works for your extra case of `(13,'LE',10)` in table 2.

The logic here is as follows:

- First full-join everything together, this will get us all rows from both sides, but matched by `id` and `indicator`.
- Calculate window counts based on: group by `id1` and count the number of matches for `id2`, and the same in reverse. Do not calculate the count for any null group.
- Then filter as follows:

  - If the two `value`s are different (but neither are null) then we have a match, so include.
  - If one side is null but there exist that `id` from the other side then include.
  - And the same the other way

Answer (score 3):

```sql
SELECT 
    L.id, L.indicator, L.[value], 
    R.id, R.indicator, R.[value] 
FROM 
(
    -- Rows from T1 with an id match in T2
    SELECT T1.*
    FROM @table1 AS T1
    JOIN @table2 AS T2
        ON T2.id = T1.id
    -- ...but not an exact match on all attributes
    EXCEPT
    SELECT T2.*
    FROM @table2 AS T2
) AS L
FULL JOIN 
(
    -- Rows from T2 with an id match in T1
    SELECT T2.*
    FROM @table2 AS T2
    JOIN @table1 AS T1 
        ON T1.id = T2.id
    -- ...but not an exact match on all attributes
    EXCEPT
    SELECT T1.*
    FROM @table1 AS T1
) AS R
    ON R.id = L.id
    AND R.indicator = L.indicator;
```

| id | indicator | value | id | indicator | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | AC | 10 | 12 | AC | 11 |
| 13 | HE | 10 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Or without a join:

```sql
SELECT 
    -- Pivot
    id1 = MAX(CASE WHEN Q1.src = 1 THEN Q1.id END),
    indicator1 = MAX(CASE WHEN Q1.src = 1 THEN Q1.indicator END),
    value1 = MAX(CASE WHEN Q1.src = 1 THEN Q1.[value] END),
    id2 = MAX(CASE WHEN Q1.src = 2 THEN Q1.id END),
    indicator2 = MAX(CASE WHEN Q1.src = 2 THEN Q1.indicator END),
    value2 = MAX(CASE WHEN Q1.src = 2 THEN Q1.[value] END)
FROM 
(
    -- Group identical source rows
    -- and add useful counts
    SELECT 
        U.id, 
        U.indicator, 
        U.[value], 
        src = MAX(U.src), 
        dupes = COUNT_BIG(*), 
        id_count = COUNT_BIG(*) OVER (
            PARTITION BY U.id
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
    FROM 
    (
        -- Combine rows remembering where they came from
        SELECT src = 1, * FROM @table1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT src = 2, * FROM @table2
    ) AS U
    GROUP BY 
        U.id, 
        U.indicator, 
        U.[value]
) AS Q1
WHERE
    -- Only records without a match
    Q1.dupes = 1
    -- Only where the id appears in both table sources
    AND Q1.id_count > 1
GROUP BY 
    Q1.id, 
    Q1.indicator
ORDER BY
    Q1.id,
    Q1.indicator;
```

| id1 | indicator1 | value1 | id2 | indicator2 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | AC | 10 | 12 | AC | 11 |
| 13 | HE | 10 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

[*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/akJ1BWvI) for both.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.indicator,t1.value,t2.id,t2.indicator,t2.value
FROM @table1 t1
FULL JOIN @table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.indicator = t2.indicator
WHERE t1.value <> t2.value 
  OR t1.id IS NULL AND t2.id IN (select id from @table1)
  OR t2.id IS NULL AND t1.id IN (select id from @table2)
```

Comment: what if i add (13,'LE',10) to table 2  if thats the case, all value in table 1 will be null

Comment: @NeverStopLearning I don’t understand what your goal is then. If a matching record hasn’t been found in table 1 then table 1 columns will be null. You need to read up on how full join works

Comment: because you only considered if table 1 has has same ID but different indicator and value. What if I add (13,'LE',10) into table 2? If that's the case, the result set should also include (NULL,NULL,NULL,13,LE,10). Because, 13 can be find in table 1 as well, but with different indicator and value

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to add more records to **@table1** and **@table2** as you said:

```
declare @table1 table (id int, indicator varchar(20),value int);
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES
(11,'AC',80),
(11,'HE',90),
(12,'AC',10),
(12,'HE',80),
(13,'AC',10),
(13,'HE',10),
(null,null,null);


declare @table2 table(id int, indicator varchar(20),value int);
INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES
(11,'AC',80),
(11,'HE',90),
(12,'AC',11),
(12,'HE',80),
(13,'AC',10),
(14,'AC',10),
(13,'LE',10);
```

#### Please check if this fulfills your requirements.

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) AS [ID table1],
       COALESCE(t1.indicator, t2.indicator) AS [Indicator table1],
       t1.[value] AS [Value table1],
       t2.[value] AS [Value table2],
       t2.id AS [ID table2],
       t2.indicator AS [Indicator table2]
FROM @table1 t1
FULL JOIN @table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.indicator = t2.indicator
WHERE t1.[value] IS NULL OR t2.[value] IS NULL OR t1.[value] <> t2.[value]
ORDER BY [ID table1], [Indicator table1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.  But could we eliminate 14 from the result set? Because first I want to check if both table has the same ID, If yes, then we need to check if indicator has the same value. That being said, 14 only exist in table 2, so I dont need this record

Comment: same concept, (NULL,NULL,NULL) from table1 should also not include in result set.